# django __init__.py file not executing pygame code

Tags: python

I'm currently developing a website using django that stores the IP address of people who access the site in a database. The idea is, that every week at midnight the website completes a traceroute on every item in the database and then maps the geographical location of each hop to the destination onto a map using pygame. This map is then stored as an image and shown on the website.

Currently, everything works individually as it should.

My **init**.py file currently looks something like this:

```
import subprocess, sys
print "Starting scripts..."
P = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "backgroundProcess.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print "...Scripts started"
```

When running this from the command prompt, or even from the gui it works fine, and the map is drawn correctly if the time is right. However when the script is run when the website is started, the text is printed correctly (Starting scripts... and ...scripts started) but the map is not drawn. In short, my question is: Does django limit what you can do in the **init**.py files?

Comment: Django does not put any specific limit on what you can do in an `__init__.py` file, but it's a very bad practice in Python to have script code like this in a package's `__init__.py`.  Also, I just don't see (from your problem's description) how anything of this relates to Django or Pygame.

Comment: how do you suggest I do this then? Is there an easier method of doing this, instead of using the _init__.py to start a script that always checks whether it's the right time to render a new map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code at a module top level (whether it's a package's `__init__.py` or just any regular module) is only executed once per process on the first import of this module. Since Django is served using long-running processes, this code will only get executed when a new process is started.

The simplest solution for a scheduled background task is to write a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) and call it from a cron job (or whatever available scheduler on your system). You really don't need that subprocess stuff here...